# Python; trying to write in a external document with a variable

Tags: python

I'm having troubles with this code:

```
import random
import time

y = 0

while y <3:
x = 0
y += 1
numlist = []

while x <5:
    x += 1
    four = random.randint (1,4)
    twelve = random.randint (1,12)
    newint = 10 + twelve /four
    round (newint)
    numlist.append (newint)

strength = numlist[0]
skill = numlist[1]
health = numlist[2]
dexterity = numlist[3]

round (strength, 10)
round (skill, 10)
round (health, 10)
round (dexterity, 10)

print (strength)
print (skill)
print (health)
print (dexterity)

str(strength)
str(skill)
str(health)
str(dexterity)

doc = open ("character1", "w")
doc.write ("Strength is")
doc.write (strength)
doc.close()
```

Output:

```
13.0

10.25

11.75

15.5


Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "D:\LOCATION OF CODE, line 41, in <module>
    doc.write (strength)   
TypeError: must be str, not float
```

This is strange; I have already defined it as a string, so I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Code like `round (newint)` does nothing - or to be precise: It rounds `newint` and ignores the result.

Comment: In future, please reduce your code to the [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the problem, and ensure your question is correctly formatted - it helps to be clear what is code, what is input and what is output.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make it a string.

```
strength = str(strength)
```

Just saying

```
str(strength)
```

doesn't change its type.

Comment: Or, combine the two: `doc.write(str(strength))`

Comment: Yeah, but from his code I assumed he thought he was making strength a string with `str(strength)` I was wanting to clarify that for him.

Answer (score 1):

> "I have already defined it as a string"

No, you haven't. `str()` does **not** alter the input object, it creates a **new object** and returns it *. You need to *assign* that new object back to the *name* that referred to the old one, e.g.:

```
strength = str(strength)
```

* *except in the case that the argument is already a string; then you get the same object back.*

Answer (score 0):

the mistake you have done is

```
str(strength)
str(skill)
str(health)
str(dexterity)
```

you tried to convert the variable to string but not saved it to the corresponding variable

try

```
strength=str(strength)
skill=str(skill)
health=str(health)
dexeterity=str(dexterity)
```